# Why do I get a TypeError here?

Tags: python-2.7

```
if emp in like_list[j]:
```

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Both `emp` and `like_list` are lists containing strings.

Answer (score 2):

Because both `emp` and `like_list` are lists, you are essentially looking for a list within a list.

If you're trying to match any element within list `emp`, you can iterate over the list like this:

```
for element in emp:
    if element in like_list:
        --do something--
    else:
        --do something else--
```

Alternatively, if `like_list` were a list of lists, your `if` statement would work.

Answer (score 0):

If both `emp` and `like_list` are lists of strings, the expression `emp in like_list[j]` is checking if a list is a member of a single string. When I tested it out with the code below I got a slightly different `TypeError`:

```
>>> emp = ["foo", "bar"]
>>> like_list = ["baz", "quux"]
>>> if emp in like_list[0]:
...     print "found"
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

This says that you can't test non-strings for membership in a string. I think fixing this will be pretty easy, but it's not entirely clear what you were trying to do.

If you want to check if the string `like_list[j]` has one of the strings in `emp` as a substring, use:

```
if any(s in like_list[j] for s in emp):
```

If instead you want to see if `like_list[j]` is equal to one of the strings in `emp`, you need to turn around the `in` expression:

```
if like_list[j] in emp:
```